# How to align date based on the next row in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data similar to what we see below. In the actual data, 1 `PATIENT_ID` may have more than 2 rows.

```
df
# PATIENT_ID DRUG_CLASS start      end        duration 
# <dbl>      <chr>      <date>     <date>     <drtn>   
#          1 SU         2014-03-05 2016-08-04  883 days
#          1 DPP4       2016-07-22 2016-08-26   35 days
#          2 SU         2014-01-07 2017-06-23 1263 days
#          2 DPP4       2015-03-04 2017-12-27 1029 days
#          3 SU         2014-01-09 2014-12-05  330 days
#          3 SU         2015-01-08 2016-01-07  364 days
```

What I want to do is to take the first row for every patient, but if the interval overlaps with the next interval, in the next row, then we take the `end` date to be the `start` date of the subsequent row `- 1`. Example:

1. For 1st patient, since the `end` date is greater than the `start` date of the next row, i.e. `"2016-08-04"` > `"2016-07-22"`, then the new `end` date should be `"2016-07-21"`
2. Similarly, for the 2nd patient, we take the new `end` date as `"2015-03-04" - 1 = "2015-03-03"`
3. For the last patient, since there is no overlapping, take the first row as-is

**Final Data:**

```
df
# PATIENT_ID DRUG_CLASS start      end        
# <dbl>      <chr>      <date>     <date>        
#          1 SU         2014-03-05 2016-07-21  
#          2 SU         2014-01-07 2015-03-03 
#          3 SU         2014-01-09 2014-12-05
```

**Code:**

```
df <- structure(list(PATIENT_ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), DRUG_CLASS = c("SU", 
"DPP4", "SU", "DPP4", "SU", "SU"), start = structure(c(16134, 
17004, 16077, 16498, 16079, 16443), class = "Date"), end = structure(c(17017, 
17039, 17340, 17527, 16409, 16807), class = "Date"), duration = structure(c(883, 
35, 1263, 1029, 330, 364), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just double check that the arranging of dates works okay

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  arrange(PATIENT_ID, start) %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    x1 = lead(start, 1L, dmy("01/01/2999"))-1,
    end_new = if_else(end > x1, x1, end)
  ) %>%
  select(-x1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% 
  mutate(new_end = min(coalesce(lead(start), end) - 1, end)) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 1) %>% 
  select(PATIENT_ID, DRUG_CLASS, start, end = new_end) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  PATIENT_ID DRUG_CLASS start      end       
       <dbl> <chr>      <date>     <date>    
1          1 SU         2014-03-05 2016-07-21
2          2 SU         2014-01-07 2015-03-03
3          3 SU         2014-01-09 2014-12-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect for `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>% 
  summarise(DRUG_CLASS = toString(unique(DRUG_CLASS)),
            end= if_else(first(end) > last(start) , max(start)-1, min(end)),
            start = first(start)) %>% 
  select(1:2, start, end)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  PATIENT_ID DRUG_CLASS start      end       
       <dbl> <chr>      <date>     <date>    
1          1 SU, DPP4   2014-03-05 2016-07-21
2          2 SU, DPP4   2014-01-07 2015-03-03
3          3 SU         2014-01-09 2014-12-05
```